# Is there a way to enclose all values with double quotes when export to csv with Pandas? (But not column names)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to be able to enclose all values when exporting to csv with double quotes but not enclose the column names with double quotes. I want to use the pandas library for the export to csv.

This is my current output

```
"Col1","Col2"
"val1","10"
"val2","15"
"val3","14"
```

This is what I want my output to be

```
Col1,Col2
"val1","10"
"val2","15"
"val3","14"
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `('"' + df.astype(str)+'"').to_csv("filename.csv")`?

Comment: That returns each value = """val1"""

Comment: You did not provide a reproducable example. Please try including one next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

data = [['val1', 10], ['val2', 15], ['val3', 14]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Col1', 'Col2'])

df = df.astype(str).applymap(lambda x: '"' + x + '"')

df.to_csv('file.csv',index=False,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Answer (score -1):

One approach is to write the header & rows separately.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['val1','val2','val3','val4'], 'col2': ['val1','val2','val3','val4']})

with open('filename.csv', 'w') as f:
    header_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    header_writer.writerow(df.columns) 
    df.to_csv(f, sep=',', header=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, index=None)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try with `regex`,here is the example.

```py
import re
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col1':['A','B'],
    'Col2':['C','D']
})
for column in df.columns:
    df[column] = df[column].apply(lambda x: f'"{x}"')
text = df.to_csv(index=None)
text = re.sub('"+','"',text)
print(text)
```

Output:

```
Col1,Col2
"A","C"
"B","D"
```